# gettext not working for Email Address

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use gettext to change the "Username" and "Email Address" fields of my wordpress registration page. I only need them to be changed on the registration page though. I am using the function for "Username", but the same thing does not work for "Email Address". I would also like to figure out how to make sure it doesn't change the label on the login page, just the registration page.

```
function username_change( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
        if ($text == 'Username') {
            $translated_text = 'Email Address * (Will be used as username)';
        }
        return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'username_change', 20, 3 );

function email_change( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
        if ($text == 'Email Address ') {
            $translated_text = 'Confirm Email';
        }
        return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'email_change', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Is the trailing space in the string 'Email Address ' deliberate? `if ($text == 'Email Address ')`

Comment: It was. I was just trying different things. There is technically an * to represent a required field, so I tried with the space and the * to see if it would work.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using the default WordPress registration page - `/wp-login.php?action=register`, you should check for "E-mail" instead of "Email Address", like this:

```
function email_change( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
        if ( !empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'register' && $text == 'E-mail' ) {
            $translated_text = 'Confirm Email';
        }
        return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'email_change', 10, 3 );
```